# Selenium Webdriver dependsOnMethod with C# and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, visual-studio-2013

I found this Java example, that makes it possible to run test methods in a sequential order.

```
@Test(priority = 10)
public void login(){...}

@Test(priority = 20, dependsOnMethods = "login")
public void verifyUserLogin() {...}
```

How would the same thing be achieved with a Visual Studio MSTest project and C#?

Comment: So when you're saying not NUnit, am I right in assuming you're using MsTest?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, edited the post to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx):

There's no quick attribute that can be applied to a suite of tests, but there's a concept of an "Ordered Test". In order to create these, you'll first need a compiled suite of tests, contained in a Visual Studio Test Project.

So let's assume we have these three tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class SampleTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
    }
}
```

Now right click anywhere within the project in Solution Explorer and choose Add > Ordered Test:

[image: Add - Ordered Test]

This will generate an ordered test, with a wizard type UI. You can now pick and choose your tests that you want to run as part of the ordered test and add them to the right hand window. You can reorder the tests using the arrows on the right hand side:

[image]

The way you run an ordered test is the same as you would run a normal test, and they will appear with the name you gave it in your Test Explorer window:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to hide the 'TestMethod1', '...2', '...3' in the Test Explorer?

Comment: You can create a custom playlist for your ordered tests, select your ordered tests, right-click and choose "Add to Playlist" > "New Playlist"